# Is the communication between transponder car key and car digital or analog?

Tags: induction, wireless-charging

I am surprised to not find much info on-line about the technology and communication technique that car immobilizer systems use to communicate with the transponder key.

To be more specific, my 2001 auto has a transponder key. When put in the ignition, a coil in the ignition puts out an electrical field that induces power in a tiny coil in my car key (which does not have its own power source.)

What does the key transmit back to the ignition?  I dont think it is a digital stream of ones and zeroes.  I suppose the key is disrupting the electrical field that the ignition coil is emitting.  What is the key doing that allows a variety of different responses so that there can be many different  UNIQUE keys to allow the whole concept to work?

Comment: All real-world digital systems are analog if you look at them carefully enough.

Comment: `the key is disrupting the electrical field that the ignition coil is emitting` ...for what reason?

Answer (score 3):

Any signal that propagates through the air is analog, by definition.

The data encoded in these analog signals, however, is pretty certainly digital.

> I suppose the key is disrupting the electrical field that the ignition coil is emitting.

Certainly not. There is a separate receiver, probably a pretty tightly integrated one, that gets the digital data (bits) back out of the air and then allows the car to be started.

Comment: I totally agree.  Car key fob signals vary in amplitude

Answer (score 3):

> I don't think its a digital stream of 1's and 0's.

It is.

> I suppose the key is disrupting the electrical field that the ignition coil is emitting

The ignition coil is the coil under the hood of the car used to generate high voltage for the spark plugs. **It has nothing to do with the immobilizer,** other than the immobilizer system not enabling the ignition when the data exchange fails/the key is not recognized.

The immobilizer is a little computer network with three or more nodes, two of them fairly dumb:

1. The engine control unit (ECU) computer,
2. The ignition switch transponder unit (it has a simple MCU usually),
3. The transponder in the key/fob, which doesn't need an MCU, but some modern ones do, as tiny MCUs can readily run with the low power available to that transponder.

The communication between the ECU and the ignition switch transponder sometimes is relayed through other car network nodes. This depends on how fancy the car's network is.

> what is the key doing that allows a variety of different responses so that there can be many different UNIQUE keys to allow the whole concept to work?

The key has a transponder. That transponder has an antenna coil, and a resonant circuit coupled to a specialized chip (ASIC). Those are often packaged in a little sealed glass ampoule buried in the key or the fob.

The key/fob coil is used to both transmit and receive data and provide power to the transponder in the key/fob.

The ASIC in the key/fob has some sort of cryptographic-ish functionality that makes it hard-ish to duplicate. Although in most cases these were in-house designs done by people with no training in cryptography, and thus were reverse engineered and broken within a couple years of release on the market. Don't home-brew cryptography, it never goes well.

There's another, powered transponder somewhere near the ignition switch, or in the key fob slot (Prius, etc.), with the coil sometimes wrapped around the ignition switch, that gets power from the car's system and acts as an intermediary between the ECU and the transponder in the key.

There are different widely-used de-facto standards for this communication, but the general concept is the same.

More modern cars support a "key in the pocket" scheme where the "key" is either a dedicated fob or a smartphone. Bluetooth is usually used for communication, although then the formerly passively powered node in the key/fob needs its own battery.

> is the communication between transponder car key and car digital or analog

The data being exchanged is digital, but there's always some analog signal processing and/or adaptation involved. Always. "Pure digital" exists in textbooks only. In practice, every digital circuit has non-ideal behaviors that are analyzed in the analog domain.

The dichotomy is rather useless, even in case of "pure digital" computer networks.

> I am surprised to not find much info on-line about the technology and communication technique that car immobilizer systems use to communicate to transponder key

Everything needed is available on-line, but the audience is rather technical, so those won't be descriptions for the lay person, nor even for an automotive technician - they don't need to know the low-level details just to service the things. The information you want is spread across technical standards (non-free in almost all cases), ASIC documentation - parts of it needing an NDA and a business entity to access, etc.

Unfortunately, the auto industry is rather famous for security by obscurity and overengineering, i.e. the stuff they put out is often secure only because it's so daunting to reverse engineer, not because there's good cryptography behind it. This is slowly changing, but 20 years ago it was a given.

Comment: in a 2001 car it's not certain that the antenna directly connects to an ASIC. Also, not all antennas are coils! :) And most car manufacturers went through more than two systems since the early 2000s ;)

Comment: But in principle, 100% on point, this answer.

Comment: *in a 2001 car it's not certain that the antenna directly connects to an ASIC* In the key or fob? Sure, there's typically a glass ampoule with a coil in it and a chip, and maybe an external capacitor, and that's about it. *not all antennas are coils!* In this specific case, they almost always are, just like in any other active-passive NFC system.

Answer (score 0):

These things typically work by adding and removing a diode short circuit on their internal antenna.

This results in a reflected signal at twice the incident frequency modulated with on/off keying (OOK). so, an RF signal carrying digital data.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of keys work similarly to contactless chip credit cards or hotel room access cards. It's basic RFID stuff.

The host system (the car) has a coil that energizes the key and sends a challenge. The key responds with an answer, and if the car authenticates it the car is allowed to start. The low-level details are security-by-obscurity, but for that vintage of a car it will be some kind of simple password.

More about that here: https://www.carkeyaction.com/how-to-duplicate-car-keys-with-chips

The newer, 'active' key fobs do this too, but at a longer distance and with a more robust algorithm such as rolling code.

Fun fact: if you have one of these fobs and it a dead battery, you can hold it next to the car's 'start engine' button, which has a coil to energize the fob.

Another fun fact: be careful where you hang your keys. An antenna relay attack is possible if the thieves can get one end of the relay close enough to your key fob.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description of what was known as the Chrysler "Sentry Key" immobilizer system that was installed in high-end chrysler vehicles in the 1999 - 2004 time frame.  This included Chrysler 300m, LHS, and some Jeep models.

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1588167/Chrysler-300m-2002.html?page=446

This system was, to my understanding, not able to be bypassed or circumvented by would-be criminals no matter what tools they might have been able to have with them.